# Model (Product) attributes used in product, alert, predefined search.. is it right with DRY concept?

Tags: django, schema, structure, models, dry

First of all I would like to mention that I am not an experienced programmer.

Say there's a model Product, and there are some types of products with different attributes (well, 2 types for example).

I have one BaseProduct model with User, creation_date, creation_ip and some more attributes and subclassed child models with specified for this type of product attributes.

```
Class BaseProduct(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    type = models.CharField()
    creation_date = models.DateField()
    creation_ip = models.IpAddressfield()

class ProductTypeX(BaseProduct):
    attribute_1 = models.ForeignKey(some_other_model)
    attribute_2 = models.ForeignKey(some_other_model2)

class ProductTypeY(BaseProduct):
    attribute_1 = models.ForeignKey(some_other_model)
    attribute_2 = models.ForeignKey(some_other_model2)
```

There's an option creating email alert on creation of new product based on some criteria, and there's also a "quick predefined search" based on some criteria too. For these I've created (again...) models.

```
class BaseAlert(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    email = models.BooleanField()
    sms = models.BooleanField()

ProductTypeXAlert(BaseAlert):
    attribute_1 = models.ForeignKey(some_other_model)
    attribute_2 = models.ForeignKey(some_other_model2)

ProductTypeYAlert(BaseAlert):
    attribute_1 = models.ForeignKey(some_other_model1)
    attribute_2 = models.ForeignKey(some_other_model2)

class BasePredefinedSearch(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

ProductTypeXPredefinedSearch(BasePredefinedSearch):
    attribute_1 = models.ForeignKey(some_other_model1)
```

Is this the right solution or should I create some universal Attribute model for alert, predefinedsearch ??.. I am repeating attributes fields here many times. What is your opinion on that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would make an AttributesBase abstract model and use multiple inheritance:

```
class AttributesBase(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    attribute1 = models.ForeignKey(SomeOtherModel1)
    attribute2 = models.ForeignKey(SomeOtherModel2)


class ProductTypeX(BaseProduct, AttributesBase):
    """Defines product type X"""
```

Hope that helps you out.